# multi-threaded consumer,producer C code, not performing?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, consumer, producer

I'm trying to do a simple multi-threaded consumer/producer, where multiple reader and writer thread, read from a file to the buffer and then from buffer back into a file. It should be thread safe. however, it is not performing as i expected. It halts half way but everytime on a different line? 
Please help me understand what I am doing wrong?!?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//TODO Define global data structures to be used
#define BUF_SIZE 5
FILE *fr;
FILE *to;            /* declare the file pointer */

struct _data {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond_read;
    pthread_cond_t cond_write;
    int condition;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    int datainbuffer;
}dc1 = {
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,0,{0},0
};


void *reader_thread(void *arg) {
    //TODO: Define set-up required
    struct _data *d = (struct _data *)arg;
    int killreaders = 0;
    while(1) {
        //TODO: Define data extraction (queue) and processing

        pthread_mutex_lock(&d->mutex);

        while (d->condition == 0 || d->datainbuffer<=0){
            pthread_cond_wait( &d->cond_read, &d->mutex );
            if(killreaders == 1){
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->mutex);
                pthread_cond_signal(&d->cond_read);
                pthread_cond_signal(&d->cond_write);
                return NULL;
            }

        }
        d->condition = 0;

        int i;
        char res;
        //if the buffer is not full, that means the end of file is reached and it time to kill the threads remaining.
        if(d->datainbuffer!=BUF_SIZE)
            killreaders = 1;

        for (i=0; i<(sizeof d->datainbuffer); i++) {
            res = d->buffer[i];
            printf("to file:%c",res);
            fputc(res, to);
        }
        d->datainbuffer = 0;


        pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal( &d->cond_write );


    }

    return NULL;
}

void *writer_thread(void *arg) {
    //TODO: Define set-up required
    struct _data *d = (struct _data *)arg;
    char * pChar;
    int killwriters = 0;

    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&d->mutex);
        while( d->condition == 1 || d->datainbuffer>0){
            pthread_cond_wait( &d->cond_write, &d->mutex );
            if(killwriters==1){
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->mutex);
                pthread_cond_signal(&d->cond_write);
                pthread_cond_signal(&d->cond_read);
                return NULL;

            }
        }
        d->condition = 1;
        int i;
        char rc;
        for (i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; i++){
            if((rc = getc(fr)) == EOF){
                killwriters = 1;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->mutex);
                pthread_cond_signal(&d->cond_read);

                return NULL;
            }
            d->datainbuffer = i+1;
            d->buffer[i] = rc;
            printf("%c",rc);
        }

        int m = 0;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&d->cond_read);


    }


    return NULL;
}


#define M 10
#define N 20
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct _data dc=dc1;

    fr = fopen ("from.txt", "rt");  /* open the file for reading */
    if (fr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file!");
        return 1;
    }
    to = fopen("to.txt", "wt");


    int i;
    pthread_t readers[N];
    pthread_t writers[M];


    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        pthread_create(&readers[i], NULL, reader_thread, (void*)&dc);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) { 
        pthread_create(&writers[i], NULL, writer_thread, (void*)&dc);
    }
    fclose(fr);
    fclose(to);

    return 0;   
}
```

any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please update with the changes you made it will help me as im looking at a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your threads are reading from and writing to files, which you open & close in main.  But main doesn't explicitly wait for the threads to finish before closing those files.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the problem pointed out by Scott Hunter, your readers and writers do all their "real work" while holding the mutex, defeating the point of having more than one thread in the first place.

Readers should operate as follows:

1) Acquire mutex.
2) Block on the condition variable until work is available.
3) Remove work from queue, possibly signal condition variable.
4) Release mutex.
5) Process the work.
6) Go to step 1.

Writers should operate as follows:

1) Get the information we need to write.
2) Acquire the mutex.
3) Block on the condition variable until there is space on the queue.
4) Place information in the queue, possibly signal condition variable.
5) Release the mutex.
6) Go to step 1.

Notice both threads do the "real work" without holding the mutex? Otherwise, why have multiple threads if only one of them can do work at a time?

Comment: Because that's where the race condition is?  Or are you saying that acquiring the mutex is unnecessary, b/c cond_wait does that for you?  -- Never mind (I'd read the "should operate" lists as "do operate" :)

Comment: thanks that was really helpful! I took your advise and it performs alot better now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether my answer is going to help you or not.. but I'm going to give my best by giving you some reference code.

I have written a similar program (except that it does not write to the file, instead display the queue-/produced-/consumed- items in the `stdout`). It can be found here - https://github.com/sangeeths/pc . I have separated the command-line processing and queue logic into a separate files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used the queue implementation from your code, since its alot easier to add and remove items from it, thanks!

Comment: @user1127217 I'm glad you could reuse some of my code. If you find it useful, please feel free to upvote and select this as an answer. Also please share you code so that I can review and learn how different that is from mine. Thanks!